# The 'ok' on the 'Your Answer' dialog on unregistered sites is a bit too high

Tags: bug, design, unregistered-users

The 'ok' on the 'Your Answer' dialog on unregistered sites is a bit too high:

[image]
[image]

You can see the top of the `k` is outside the actual box, increasing the `margin-top` by 10px in the containing div fixes it.

Comment: +1 for the bug. -1 for the NonFreehand in the second case. +1 for the shadow.