# Can we auto-hide the 'Thanks for contributing an answer...' box when the focus goes away from the textarea?

Tags: feature-request, unregistered-users

For unregistered users, when you click the textarea for answering a question, a big box comes up with information on how to answer, but when you click away, it should go away itself, you shouldn't have to click the already [way-too-high ok button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252171/the-ok-on-the-your-answer-dialog-on-unregistered-sites-is-a-bit-too-high) to get rid of it!

This shows what I mean:
[image]

If not immediately, at least hide it after a few seconds of the textarea being out of focus!

Comment: I have no idea what your question is, I just upvoted because stuff is moving around in your question... Beats freehand circles hands down.

Comment: I don't think it should close by clicking anywhere outside of it. We want to reduce Not An Answers that come in by unregistered users that aren't familiar with the site. By closing that box by clicking outside of it, it can easily be closed by mistake. The OK button should definitely be bigger, more noticeable, and it might be better to change it to "X" or "close"  instead of "ok".

Comment: @Roombatron5000 I seriously doubt that the message actually helps stopping NAAs; I think the actual problem might be that it's impossible to open that message again once it's gone - I think clicking the help button again should bring back the message, and then clicking again should remove the help under the toolbar. But it's annoying when you have to manually close it - how about hiding it when you ***start scrolling*** and showing it again when ***the textarea regains focus***?

Comment: Looks like a z-index issue in gif.

Comment: When it goes up and down, comment text is over "your answer".

Comment: hmmm... that seems to happen normally as well (not problem with gif)

Comment: What did you make that gif on? And what screen recording software is it? (just wondering)...

Comment: @Tim http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7019/make-a-gif-video ;p

Answer (score -1):

I do not think this is a good idea, people usually tend to ignore tool-tip-like boxes, and since this is intended for unregistered users, I think the way it is now is OK.

I actually suggest that, the [Post Your Answer] button to be dimmed (disabled) until the user click "OK" on that box, just as an extra step to emphasize for unregistered users that the information in that box is important and to be followed. Also, the "OK" should be made bigger and changes to something like "Agree & Continue to Answer".

Comment: I don't get you - `people usually tend to ignore tool-tip-like boxes` - if that is the big box - why should it even be there? There's no point making someone click 'ok' - because anyone who didn't read it in the first place won't read it if they're asked - they'll just click ok to please the system.