# The on screen back button on user profile's specific site opens drawer menu instead of going back to previous view

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, android-app, navigation

The following procedures seem to reproduce it every time:

1. Find a question
2. Click on any user's name
3. Click on any site's name
4. Click the back button on the top left of the screen
5. Instead of going back, it opens the left panel. Clicking the physical back button on my phone works, however.

Here's a walkthrough on the bug. This is ran on ARC (the same behavior is seen on a physical device). Tested on the latest version 1.0.60.
[image]

Comment: @MARamezani This bug only exists in the SE app...

Comment: @Tim App Inventor? Is that some kind of program that let's beginners to create Android apps? Instead of that, if it keeps crashing, you can use the actual Android SDK (Eclipse) to run your code (given that the app is written in actual Java code) with its included emulator. The best thing is that it has a debugger. Or if you just want to run an apk file you can always use ARC (it's much faster).

Comment: @Tim I use [LICEcap](https://github.com/lepht/licecap).

Comment: Me too :P http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252181/can-we-auto-hide-the-thanks-for-contributing-an-answer-box-when-the-focus-g#comment823907_252181 wish it worked better on linux but there you go...

Answer (score 4):

Cool catch! This is fixed as of the next version (anything with a version code higher than 1.0.60).

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi-Nice!